Google Workspace LDAP Filter by UID in Multi-Domain Structure
I'm having some issues and confusion regarding Google Workspace LDAP and LDAP in general.
I have an organizational unit called example.com. Inside this organizational unit in Google, I have sub-units named example.co, example.es, and example.it. The structure is as follows:
* example.com
 ** example.co
 ** example.es
 ** example.it

The problem is that when using the bind path "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" and the filter "(uid=user1)" — which is a user with the attribute mail=user1@example.com — the user is found. But if I search for "(uid=user2)" — who has the attribute mail=user2@example.it — they are not found :/ ... the same happens with "co" and "es".
Initially, I thought it was due to the bind path not including "dc=es" or "dc=it". If I try with "ou=Users,dc=example" it still doesn't work. And what’s really confusing is that if I use the bind path "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" and filter by "mail=user2@example.it" it does return the result! I don't understand why it works with the mail attribute but not with the uid.
The Google VPN client has permissions to view all attributes across all OUs.
This is part of a migration from a very legacy system, and it's difficult to make some applications search by the mail field; we need them to search by uid.
(Currently, in an old OpenLDAP system we have, searches respect the UID, not the email.)
Does anyone know what I might be missing and why it works with mail? Any help is appreciated!
For all my tests, I am using ldapsearch. For example:

ldapsearch -x -D user -w pass -H ldap://x.x.x.x:636 -b 'ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com' 'uid=user2' does not work
ldapsearch -x -D user -w pass -H ldap://x.x.x.x:636 -b 'ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com' 'mail=user2@example.it' works

Thank you!
I need to perform searches throughout my root organizational unit (OU) without considering email addresses, just looking at the UID.

Can you retry with -b dc=example,dc=com and report the results?

The result is all the users of ".com" whitout ".it" users.
